# create function in php include while loop

Tags: php, mysql

i have this code to call posts from database

```
<?php
    $q = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE user_id = '$user_info[id]'  ORDER BY id DESC";
    $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

    while($post_info = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)) { ?>
```

//html

it works fine but i like to create a function includes the query and the while loop and move it to functions.php and keep the html code in template.php but I don't know how with the while loop..

```
  function data_post($dbc, $user_info['id']){

    $q = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE user_id = '$user_info[id]'  ORDER BY id DESC";
    $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

    while($post_info = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r))

   return $post_info
 }
```

I have tried this but there is no result

Comment: while($post_info = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)){ $new_array[]=$post_info;  } and return the $new_array outside of the while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function ss()
 {
   ...........

  while($post_info = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r))
  { 
    $new_array[]=$post_info; 

  } 

  return $new_array;

 }

And return the $new_array outside of the while loop

And get the value like this 

  $mm= ss();

 print_r($mm);   here you get that $new_array values
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Function Body

```
function data_post($dbc, $user_id){    
    $q = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE user_id = '$user_id' ORDER BY id DESC";
    $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

    $arrayPost = array();
    while($post_info = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)){
        $arrayPost[] = array('id' => $post_info['postId'], 'name' => $post_info['postName']);
        // or whatever data you want to return of post, insert in array
    }
    return $arrayPost;
}
```

Function Calling

```
$userPostArray = data_post($dbc, $user_info['id']);
```